# How to bold and italic object keys in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to make the KEYS of our object *italic* or **bold** in VSCODE?
for example, myObj is an object. Can I change my theme of VSCODE to always show the keys like `name` , `operator` and `values` as *italics* or **bold** ?    Right now I'm using `ONE DARK ITALIC` theme.

```
var myObj = {
  name: 'internalid',
  operator: search.Operator.NONEOF,
  values: empName
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is in a javascript file, try this:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {

  "textMateRules": [  
    {
      "scope": "meta.object-literal.key.js",
      "settings": {
        // "foreground": "#FF0000",
        "fontStyle": "bold"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can get that scope value by triggering the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` in the command palette.  And then click on code of which you want to know the scope.  In this case, clicking on a key of an object in a js file yields the scope `mete.object-literal.key.js`.  If you aren't in a js file you'll get a different scope to plug into the textmate rule.

You can also use a fontStyle `italic`.